# When is chromatography regarded as a viable industrial purification strategy?

Tags: chromatography, purification

I understand the basics that chromatography is a fairly slow and expensive process compared to direct synthesis. When a synthesis route is not feasible, the economics become favorable. Not being in the chemical industry, I do not know the specifics of these economics or how common industrial scale chromatography is.

Three applications I know of are [sucrose separation from beet molasses](https://www.arifractal.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Molasses-Desugarization-in-the-US-Beet-Sugar-Industry-Recent-Update.pdf.), [insulin from genetically modified E.coli](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4203937/), and [B-Carotene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%92-Carotene) from algae. There are surely many others especially in the pharmaceutical industry, but I have not been able to find a list of specific chemicals.

Comment: Within pharma the scale-up chemists put a lot of time in to minimising chromatographic separations for drug substances.

Comment: Most organic chemicals are purified and separated by column chromatography / TLC.

Comment: Questions that request lists are frowned upon. You could reformat the question so that it addresses an underlying concept, for instance, "when is chromatography regarded as a viable industrial purification strategy?" And adding some details regarding your own findings.

Comment: @BuckThorn, Thanks for the feedback!